# CakePHP : Getting weird warnig message and redirect() not working.Getting just blank pages

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have been working the entire day just get this solved.I baked the code for basic crud operations but Whenever an action loads(add,edit,delete) and process it, Then it doesnt redirect back to controller.It just shows a blank page.But the data seems to updating.Also I get the follwing warning in every controller.

Warning (2): preg_match(): Numeric named subpatterns are not allowed [CORE\Cake\Routing\Route\CakeRoute.php, line 191]

Warning (2): preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Numeric named subpatterns are not allowed [CORE\Cake\Routing\Route\CakeRoute.php, line 191]

here is my action for add

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Doctor->create();
        if ($this->Doctor->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The doctor has been saved'));
        return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Doctor','action'=>'index'))
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The doctor could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $patiences = $this->Doctor->Patience->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('patiences'));
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, the regex passed to `preg_match()` contains numeric named subpatterns, which isn't allowed. The regex is the compiled route, so first check your routes configuration, there might be something wrong. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you will call the add controller function, it will result in displaying the add.ctp file. Maybe you have a blank add.ctp file. 
Or to redirect to another controller just use this in your add function -

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Doctor','action'=>'index'))
```

Comment: I have add.ctp and its not the issue.I already tried $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Doctor','action'=>'index')).I think its some problem with routing.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.It was problem with routing config.
This issue is caused because  I baked a project previously with admin routing not this one.

Just removed the configuration from core.php code :

Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('whateveryoursiteaddress/controller/admin'));

thanks to ndm